# GWT UI Binder using pure HTML

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Is there a way to work with pure HTML in GWT UIBinder.

The problem I am seeing is more of where we have to wrap the style in curly braces. Any link /article/book handling UIBinder in detail would be helpful.

I have already seen the articles in GST website

Comment: You mean, you want to use `<style>` instead of `<ui:style>`? Could you provide some example of the "failing" HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't really any books that cover some of the newer GWT features like UiBinder. _GWT in Action_ was good, but is woefully outdated by now.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer. I am realizing that there is no pure HTML way of doing the things. We have to use g: widgets which are than converted into Code by GWT.

Answer (score 2):

The style name (CSS class name) must be put in curly braces, e.g. `<div class="{style.example}">...</div>`, when the name is obfuscated by GWT. GWT does this, when you use a [CssResource](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource). This is also the case, when you declare it in a `<ui:style>` block in your `.ui.xml` file:

```
<ui:UiBinder ...>
  <ui:style>
    .example {
      ...
    }
  </ui:style>

  <div class="{style.example}">
     ...
  </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In contrast, when you declare your CSS class in a plain CSS file (which you directly reference form you HTML host page), then you don't put the name in curly braces. In that case, you just use it like

```
<ui:UiBinder ...>
  <div class="example">...</div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way which is close to pure HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
  ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
  ui:generateLocales="default"
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

  <ui:style>

    ... CSS ...

  </ui:style>

  <g:HTMLPanel>

    ... HTML and GWT controls ...

  </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the answer to this question via google and landed here.
I've found the solution that worked for me here:
http://blog.sortedset.com/googles-app-engine-java/gwt-uibinder-helloworld-with-html/

The essentials:

Use

```
interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Element, MobileUI>
```

instead of

```
interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MobileUI>
```

Use

```
setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
```

instead of

```
initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
```

Use

```
RootPanel.getBodyElement().appendChild(myUiBinder.getElement());
```

instead of

```
RootPanel.get().add(myUiBinder);
```